# How to add contact group (label) programmatically with sync adapters?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have an issue with adding custom group(label) to account in `ContentProvider`.
I'm creating new operation (`ContentProviderOperation.newInsert()`) and it adds new label with given title but i need to generate `ContactsContract.Groups.SOURCE_ID` and `ContactsContract.Groups.SYNC2`,`ContactsContract.Groups.SYNC3` fields for sync adapters. I can't find an information about how to get existing sync adapters from account and how to generate `ContactsContract.Groups.SOURCE_ID` (if needed). Maybe I need to create new sync adapters?

**Here is my current code**

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops =
                new ArrayList<>();
        AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(MainActivity.this);
        Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccounts();
        for (int i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE, title)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_NAME, accounts[i].name)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_TYPE, accounts[i].type)
                    .build()
            );
        }


        try {
            ContentProviderResult[] results = getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figure it out. You just need to set `ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE`, `ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_NAME`, `ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_TYPE` and after syncing, other columns will automatically filled with generated data.